# Correlation analysis in longitudinal data using lmer

Tags: lme4-nlme

I have longitudinal data and I want to run lmer in R on it. Consider A as one continuos
independent covariat and B as my dependent one. I have also four timepoints and I want to examine the correlation between A and B in time, I'm using this formula:

fit=lmer(b=a+time+time*a+(subject|1+timepoint))

My question is that which coefficient is my anwer? the coafficient for a? time? or time*a? and what does each of them mean?

I really appreciate if anyone can help me with that!

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you start reading this nice paper:
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2515245920960351

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/325922)